# How can I pause/resume rsync

Tags: process, rsync

How can I pause an rsync that's running?

First time I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to kill it and used the `-P` flag to run again. Is this prone to corrupt the current file transfer?

Second time I simply put MacOS to sleep (by closing the lid). Looking at the running process I can see 2 (not sure why) with a status of 'S'.

Tried using

```
kill -SIGCONT
```

to resume the process, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can pause any program by sending it a `TSTP` (polite) or `STOP` (forcible) signal. On the terminal you've run `rsync` in, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> sends `TSTP`. Resume with the `fg` or `bg` command in the terminal or a `CONT` signal.

It is safe to kill an rsync process and run the whole thing again; it will continue where it left off. It may be a little inefficient, particularly if you haven't passed `--partial` (included in `-P`), because `rsync` will check all files again and process the file it was interrupted on from scratch.

There may be unusual combinations of options that will lead to some files not being synchronized properly, maybe `--inplace` with something else, but I think no single option will cause this.

If you disconnect your laptop and reconnect it somewhere else, it may get a different IP address. Then the TCP connection used by rsync would be severed, so you'd have to kill it and start again. This can also happen if you suspend your laptop and the TCP connection times out. The timeout will eventually filter out to the application level, but it can take a while. It's safe to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and run rsync again.

Comment: Actually killing `rsync -avh` simply loose the current file being copied, if the file is large you've lost quite a lot of time. Maybe `Ctrl+z` moving the temporary file (start with a dot) and then `Ctrl-C` rsync might be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation.  To clarify: ctrl+z to pause, fg to resume, bg to stop.

Comment: @Praesagus `bg` to put process to the [**b**ack**g**round](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103731/6862), not to stop.

Comment: `--partial` is what I needed. I'm trying to copy 21GB of data, and among these I have a 6.6GB file. The problem is the network kills my connection after a few GB of data transfer, for which `--partial` is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 27):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend, and:

```
$ fg
```

to continue, use

```
$ jobs
```

to see suspended jobs; `bg [number]` to background them; `fg [number]` to foreground it.

Comment: `Ctrl+S` only suspends scrolling output, not the underlying program (unless it gets blocked waiting for the terminal to accept its output), and only if you haven't disabled it.

Comment: With the current 'S' status it doesn't resume. Is it safe to kill it using Ctrl+C and run rsync again? What other options do I have? Will have that in mind next time though, thanks.

Comment: Also note that Ctrl-Z to suspend a process is likely, after some time, to result in the timeout of any TCP network connections which were established by that program.  Thus leaving an rsync suspended for more than a few minutes will very likely cause it to quit abruptly with an error message when you put it back in the foreground and it finds that its opened sockets are returning errors from reads and writes.

Comment: In my experience it is not wise to use Ctrl-Z to suspend an ongoing rsync command because (modern versions of) rsync spawn 2 worked children that do the actual work: one for getting data from the source, one for writing it to/on the destination. Those children do not necessarily get suspended, or unsuspended after you do `fg`. In any case I always had to abort the operation the times I tried to use (or accidentally used) Ctrl-Z.

Answer (score 9):

People here have mentioned using the `--partial` flag works, it needs to be mentioned however that it only resumes when the `--append` or `--append-verify` flag is used when resuming.

`--partial` creates a hidden file of the file that has not finished the sync process, the file is kept when you interrupt syncing. It continues to complete the file when you use `--append` after resuming, otherwise when not using `--append`, the incomplete hidden file is kept and remains incomplete.

**Conclusion:** You can just interrupt `rsync --partial` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> if you use `rsync --append` when resuming

(Source: [Can rsync resume after being interrupted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48298/can-rsync-resume-after-being-interrupted) retrieved 5 april 2016)

Comment: so if I have used ```rsync --avP <source> <destination>``` , I have to pause it by CTRL+C and then resume just by typing ```rysnc --append``` ?

Comment: @kingmakerking yes

Comment: @kingmakerking : No. you still need the options from your first rsync, and the source and destination. To resume, you restart your previous rsync command, and _add_ `--append` to the existing options.

Comment: Really old comments, sorry for bringing this up again: Will it work when I just add the `--append` command in general? Or will this give me issues in case there was no interrupted file from the last run?

Answer (score 8):

Run `rsync` with the `--partial` flag. It will then keep partial transfers and resume partial files when started.