# Can rsync resume after being interrupted?

Tags: rsync

I used `rsync` to copy a large number of files, but my OS (Ubuntu) restarted unexpectedly:

```
sudo rsync -azvv /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2
```

After reboot, I ran `rsync` again, but from the output on the terminal, I found that `rsync` still copied those already copied before. But I heard that `rsync` is able to find differences between source and destination, and therefore to just copy the differences.

Source and target are both NTFS. The source is an external HDD and target is an internal HDD.

I wonder in my case if `rsync` can resume what was left last time?

Comment: Yes, rsync won't copy again files that it's already copied. There are a few edge cases where its detection can fail. Did it copy all the already-copied files? What options did you use? What were the source and target filesystems? If you run rsync again after it's copied everything, does it copy again?

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks! (1) I think I saw rsync copied the same files again from its output on the terminal. (2) Options are same as in my other post, i.e. `sudo rsync -azvv /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2`. (3) Source and target are both NTFS, buy source is an external HDD, and target is an internal HDD. (3) It is now running and hasn't finished yet.

Comment: There is also the --partial flag to resume partially transferred files (useful for large files)

Comment: @Gilles: What are some "edge cases where its detection can fail"?

Comment: @Tim Off the top of my head, there's at least clock skew, and differences in time resolution (a common issue with FAT filesystems which store times in 2-second increments, the `--modify-window` option helps with that).

Comment: if you did not have / or /. at the tail end of the file source path argument then it will be making an extra copy in a subdirectory that has the same name as the source directory

Comment: Use -u to speed up.

Comment: Have a look at [aim](https://github.com/mihaigalos/aim) for downloading/uploading with resume over http(s), ftp, and ssh.

Comment: @MihaiGalos how do you install the utility?

Comment: @jarno I've added the missing installation section: https://github.com/mihaigalos/aim#installation

Answer (score 463):

First of all, regarding the "resume" part of your question, `--partial` just tells the receiving end to keep partially transferred files if the sending end disappears as though they were completely transferred.

While transferring files, they are temporarily saved as hidden files in their target folders (e.g. `.TheFileYouAreSending.lRWzDC`), or a specifically chosen folder if you set the `--partial-dir` switch. When a transfer fails and `--partial` is not set, this hidden file will remain in the target folder under this cryptic name, but if `--partial` is set, the file will be renamed to the actual target file name (in this case, `TheFileYouAreSending`), even though the file isn't complete. The point is that you can later complete the transfer by running rsync again with either `--append` or `--append-verify`.

So, `--partial` doesn't *itself* resume a failed or cancelled transfer. To resume it, you'll have to use one of the aforementioned flags on the next run. So, if you need to make sure that the target won't ever contain files that appear to be fine but are actually incomplete, you shouldn't use `--partial`. Conversely, if you want to make sure you never leave behind stray failed files that are hidden in the target directory, and you know you'll be able to complete the transfer later, `--partial` is there to help you.

With regards to the `--append` switch mentioned above, this is the actual "resume" switch, and you can use it whether or not you're also using `--partial`. Actually, when you're using `--append`, no temporary files are ever created. Files are written directly to their targets. In this respect, `--append` gives the same result as `--partial` on a failed transfer, but without creating those hidden temporary files.

So, to sum up, if you're moving large files and you want the option to resume a cancelled or failed rsync operation from the exact point that `rsync` stopped, you need to use the `--append` or `--append-verify` switch on the next attempt.

As @Alex points out below, since version 3.0.0 `rsync` now has a new option, `--append-verify`, which behaves like `--append` did before that switch existed. You probably always want the behaviour of `--append-verify`, so check your version with `rsync --version`. If you're on a Mac and not using `rsync` from `homebrew`, you'll (at least up to and including El Capitan) have an older version and need to use `--append` rather than `--append-verify`. Why they didn't keep the behaviour on `--append` and instead named the newcomer `--append-no-verify` is a bit puzzling. Either way, `--append` on `rsync` before version 3 is the same as `--append-verify` on the newer versions.

`--append-verify` isn't dangerous: It will always read and compare the data on both ends and not just assume they're equal. It does this using checksums, so it's easy on the network, but it does require reading the shared amount of data on both ends of the wire before it can actually resume the transfer by appending to the target.

Second of all, you said that you "heard that rsync is able to find differences between source and destination, and therefore to just copy the differences."

That's correct, and it's called delta transfer, but it's a different thing. To enable this, you add the `-c`, or `--checksum` switch. Once this switch is used, rsync will examine files that exist on both ends of the wire. It does this in chunks, compares the checksums on both ends, and if they differ, it transfers just the differing parts of the file. But, as @Jonathan points out below, the comparison is only done when files are of the same size on both ends — different sizes will cause rsync to upload the entire file, overwriting the target with the same name.

This requires a bit of computation on both ends initially, but can be extremely efficient at reducing network load if for example you're frequently backing up very large files fixed-size files that often contain minor changes. Examples that come to mind are virtual hard drive image files used in virtual machines or iSCSI targets.

It is notable that if you use `--checksum` to transfer a batch of files that are completely new to the target system, rsync will still calculate their checksums on the source system before transferring them. Why I do not know :)

So, in short:

If you're often using rsync to just "move stuff from A to B" and want the option to cancel that operation and later resume it, **don't** use `--checksum`, but **do** use `--append-verify`.

If you're using rsync to back up stuff often, using `--append-verify` probably won't do much for you, unless you're in the habit of sending large files that continuously grow in size but are rarely modified once written. As a bonus tip, if you're backing up to storage that supports snapshotting such as `btrfs` or `zfs`, adding the `--inplace` switch will help you reduce snapshot sizes since changed files aren't recreated but rather the changed blocks are written directly over the old ones. This switch is also useful if you want to avoid rsync creating copies of files on the target when only minor changes have occurred.

When using `--append-verify`, rsync will behave just like it always does on all files that are the same size. If they differ in modification or other timestamps, it will overwrite the target with the source without scrutinizing those files further. `--checksum` will compare the contents (checksums) of every file pair of identical name and size.

**UPDATED 2015-09-01** Changed to reflect points made by @Alex (thanks!)

**UPDATED 2017-07-14** Changed to reflect points made by @Jonathan (thanks!)

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) `--append` does **not** check the data, but `--append-verify` does.  Also, as @gaoithe points out in a comment below, the documentation claims `--partial` *does* resume from previous files.

Comment: Thank you @Alex for the updates. Indeed, since 3.0.0, `--append` no longer compares the source to the target file before appending. Quite important, really! `--partial` does not itself resume a failed file transfer, but rather leaves it there for a subsequent `--append(-verify)` to append to it. My answer was clearly misrepresenting this fact; I'll update it to include these points! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32094804/819417) says `--partial` is enough.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman RTFM ;) Or test it out yourself :)

Comment: *opens tab 526* [Using the --partial option tells rsync to keep the partial file which should make a subsequent transfer of the rest of the file much faster.](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html) [Simpler doc.](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync+--partial)

Comment: @CeesTimmerman,  I have to say I find that statement misleading, since it doesn't use the partial file in subsequent transfers.  In fact, I am *still* trying to find out how to achieve this.

Comment: I have been playing with this more, and have found a situation where `--append` and `--append-verify` are **not** safe.  "If a file needs to be transferred and its size on the receiver is the same or longer than the size on the sender, the file is skipped."  This is the case even with -c or verify!

Comment: @CeesTimmerman — You quote it and still misread it. It just says _a subsequent transfer_, it doesn't say _a subsequent transfer with just --partial_, which is why I suggested you test it for yourself.

Comment: @Alex — Interesting. The "same size" is expected, of course, but the _or longer_ part is pretty weird. Are you sure this applies to `--append-verify` as well? And also it it applies when the file stats differ, as they ought to if such a scenario were ever to occur? The guaranteed-to-work fallback would be to always use `--checksum`.

Comment: @DanielSmedegaardBuus It doesn't say with additional options either, which it should, IMO. You're right that it needs `--append` to not retransfer the file, but that skips larger destination files even when the source files are newer, even using `--append-verify`, and `--checksum` is terribly slow when there's lots of files/data. :(

Comment: So does that mean, when I'm writing an automated script (that needs to be resumable), I should always have `--partial --append-verify` together? Or does `--append-verify` imply `--partial`? Also what about `--partial-dir`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai `--partial --append-verify` would do the trick. `--partial-dir` cannot be used alongside an append switch, although it would be nice. Just keep in mind that files on the receiving end may appear to be "normal" even though they're not fully uploaded (while uploading, or after a failure until it is re-attempted).

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Actually, check out Alexander's answer below about `--partial-dir` — looks like it's the perfect bullet for this. I may have missed something entirely ;)

Comment: @DanielSmedegaardBuus I tested it out myself on a slow connection, and this is what I see with _only_ `--partial`: rsync copies the file into the temporary name, connection is interrupted, the remote rsync eventually moves that file to the regular name and quits, then upon re-running with `--partial` and _without_ `--append`, the new temporary file is initialized with a copy of the partially-transferred remote file, then the copy continues from where the connection died. (Ubuntu 14.04 / rsync 3.1)

Comment: It seems newer versions of rsync: *version 3.1.1  protocol version 31*  default to  deleting the temporary (e.g. `.TheFileYouAreSending.lRWzDC`) partially transferred files. IIRC the older versions behaved as per this answer, by default a failed transfer leaves a `.TheFileYouAreSending.lRWzDC` type file. Nowadays it seems rsync cleans up after itself. Which makes sense, if those temporary files can't be used for a resume operation, then they are just clutter really. See `man rsync | less '+/By default, rsync will delete'`

Comment: What's your level of confidence in the described behavior of `--checksum`? According to the [`man`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) it has more to do with deciding which files to flag for transfer than with delta-transfer (which, presumably, is `rsync`'s default behavior).

Comment: I share @JonathanY.'s concerns; if you read up on the `-W` flag in the man-page, it hints that for non-local paths the use of delta-transfers is the default behavior.

Comment: I wish the "So, in short" part were at the top of the answer so I didn't have to read through it every time I look up this post (I keep forgetting the switch to use). Would you add a "TL;DR" at the top, maybe?

Comment: Per the man: 
`-W, --whole-file  With this option rsync’s delta-transfer algorithm is not used (...) This is the default when both the source and destination are specified as local paths. (...)   --stats  This tells rsync to print a verbose set of statistics on the file transfer, allowing you to tell how effective rsync’s delta-transfer algorithm is for your data. `

This tends to imply that delta-transfer is the default.

Indeed, `-checksum` is about determining if a file has changed (by checksumming at both ends, thus reading all files from disk when they have the same size&date).

Comment: Add TL;DR with short answer.

Comment: `man rsync` says that `--inplace` is automatically used if a resend is required on a verification failure.

Comment: ohhh hello old friend, new year same revisit to this question and answer. it ages like wine 

Comment: This answer is partially wrong. delta-transfer is rsync's default, so you don't need to use `--append` or `--append-verify`. `--partial` is enough. The difference is that without `--append-verify` the already existing file is copied to a temp file, while with `--append-verify` it writes directly to the destination file. In both cases the already existing content is checksum checked.

Comment: @mgutt `--append` tells rsync to append onto smaller files in the target folder with the same name as a source. Without it, it will overwrite the smaller file on the target with the larger file from the source. `--append-verify` first verifies that the smaller file's data is identical to the initial portion of the source file - if not, it also overwrites. `--partial` tells rsync to keep a partially transferred file when exiting, otherwise it deletes it. So, with the combination of these arguments, you can effectively cancel rsync in the middle of transferring a large file, and resume it later.

Comment: "Without it, it will overwrite the smaller file" This is wrong. As I said delta-transfer is the default. overwriting is only done if you use `--whole-file` (which disables delta-transfer).

Comment: Sadly almost all of this is completely wrong for the use case (now) shown in the question, which is a local to local filesystem copy

Answer (score 103):

## TL;DR:

Just specify a partial directory as the rsync man pages recommends:

```
--partial-dir=.rsync-partial
```

---

## Longer explanation:

There is actually a built-in feature for doing this using the `--partial-dir` option, which has several advantages over the `--partial` and `--append-verify`/`--append` alternative.

### Excerpt from the rsync man pages:

```
--partial-dir=DIR
      A  better way to keep partial files than the --partial option is
      to specify a DIR that will be used  to  hold  the  partial  data
      (instead  of  writing  it  out to the destination file).  On the
      next transfer, rsync will use a file found in this dir  as  data
      to  speed  up  the resumption of the transfer and then delete it
      after it has served its purpose.

      Note that if --whole-file is specified (or  implied),  any  par-
      tial-dir  file  that  is  found for a file that is being updated
      will simply be removed (since rsync  is  sending  files  without
      using rsync's delta-transfer algorithm).

      Rsync will create the DIR if it is missing (just the last dir --
      not the whole path).  This makes it easy to use a relative  path
      (such  as  "--partial-dir=.rsync-partial")  to have rsync create
      the partial-directory in the destination file's  directory  when
      needed,  and  then  remove  it  again  when  the partial file is
      deleted.

      If the partial-dir value is not an absolute path, rsync will add
      an  exclude rule at the end of all your existing excludes.  This
      will prevent the sending of any partial-dir files that may exist
      on the sending side, and will also prevent the untimely deletion
      of partial-dir items on the receiving  side.   An  example:  the
      above  --partial-dir  option would add the equivalent of "-f '-p
      .rsync-partial/'" at the end of any other filter rules.
```

By default, rsync uses a random temporary file name which gets deleted when a transfer fails. As mentioned, using `--partial` you can make rsync keep the incomplete file *as if it were successfully transferred*, so that it is possible to later append to it using the `--append-verify`/`--append` options. However there are several reasons this is sub-optimal.

1. Your backup files may not be complete, and without checking the remote file which must still be unaltered, there's no way to know.
2. If you are attempting to use `--backup` and `--backup-dir`, you've just added a new version of this file that never even existed before to your version history.

However if we use `--partial-dir`, rsync will preserve the temporary partial file, and resume downloading using that partial file next time you run it, and we do not suffer from the above issues.

Comment: Few nits regarding `--partial-dir` and I/O amount and/or disk write operations (CF, SSD, etc): **1.** When a path which is _not_ in the same partition (another disk, RAM drive, etc.) as the files being synchronized, a file copy between the specified directory and the target will occur when done; **2.** When large files are involved, it's recommended to use a relative path (located in the _same_ partition - not a symbolic link, etc.); **3.** When using temporary storage (such as a RAM drive), one should also be aware that files to be synchronized will be limited by temporary storage free space.

Answer (score 54):

You may want to add the `-P` option to your command.

From the `man` page:

> ```
> --partial By default, rsync will delete any partially transferred file if the transfer
>          is interrupted. In some circumstances it is more desirable to keep partially
>          transferred files. Using the --partial option tells rsync to keep the partial
>          file which should make a subsequent transfer of the rest of the file much faster.
>
>   -P     The -P option is equivalent to --partial --progress.   Its  pur-
>          pose  is to make it much easier to specify these two options for
>          a long transfer that may be interrupted.
> ```

So instead of:

```
sudo rsync -azvv /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2
```

Do:

```
sudo rsync -azvvP /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2
```

Of course, if you don't want the progress updates, you can just use `--partial`, i.e.:

```
sudo rsync --partial -azvv /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2
```

Comment: @Flimm not quite correct. If there is an interruption (network or receiving side) then when using --partial the partial file is kept AND it is used when rsync is resumed. From the manpage: "Using the --partial option tells rsync to keep the partial file which should <b>make a subsequent transfer of the rest of the file much faster</b>."

Comment: @Flimm and @gaoithe, my answer wasn't quite accurate, and definitely not up-to-date. I've updated it to reflect version 3 + of `rsync`. It's important to stress, though, that `--partial` does **not** itself resume a failed transfer. See my answer for details :)

Comment: @DanielSmedegaardBuus I tried it and the `-P` is enough in my case. Versions: client has 3.1.0 and server has 3.1.1. I interrupted the transfer of a single large file with ctrl-c. I guess I am missing something.

Comment: Why `vv`? i.e. `v` used 2 times?

Comment: Where rsync save part of file with `-azvvP` ?

Comment: Just to confirm, does `-azvvP` also do checksum verifications like `append-verify` mentioned in the other answers?

Answer (score 8):

Arriving late to this, but I had the same question and I found a different answer.

The `--partial` flag ("keep partially transferred files" in `rsync -h`) is useful for large files, as is `--append` ("append data onto shorter files"), but the question is about a *large number* of files.

To avoid files that have already been copied use `-u` (or `--update`: "skip files that are newer on the receiver").

Comment: Note to self: do not use `--ignore-existing` in combination with `--append`. Rsync will leave your interrupted file as is thinking you're happy with it even if it's incomplete. This took me a bit of headscratching to realize. That's the downside of having a bunch of preconfigured options that you use routinely.

Answer (score 5):

Several important rules:

1. `rsync` use delta-xfer algorithm to determine whether to resend the blocks differ, except with `-W, --whole-file` option.
2. `rsync` will write data into a temporary directory and move to destination when complete, except with `--inplace` option.
3. when delta-xfer is enabled, if you want to skip the computing of checksum of blocks of partial sent data, you can add `--append` option, but the sameness of partial sent data should be ensured by yourself.
4. `--append` implies `--inplace`, which itself implies `--partial`

In my case, I want to send incremental files without too much CPU & disk load, the command is

```
rsync -avPL --inplace --append --bwlimit 30m -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' <src> <dst>
```

Comment: Your #1 only when transferring between two systems. If you transfer between two parts of the same filesystem the whole delta thing is disabled

Answer (score 1):

In my case rsync was failing and quitting the executable. In which case I've used this simple bash `while/do` script.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

source="/tmp/source" # Change it !
destination="/tmp/destination" # Change it !

while true
do
  if rsync -avz --partial $source $destination; then # SC2181
    echo "rsync completed normally"
    exit
  else
    echo "Rsync failure. Backing off and retrying in 180s..."
    sleep 180
  fi
done
```

Before running the script, you have to set `source` and `destination` to values of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR

This will resume partial transfers, and add compression for faster transfers

```bash
rsync --partial --progress --archive --compress --compress-choice=zstd --compress-level=9 --checksum-choice=xxh3 user@host:~/my_file.txt .
```

#### Flag explanation

`--partial`: Resume partial file transfer

`--progress`: Show transfer progress and ETA

`--archive`: Preserve file attributes

`--compress`: Enable compression (zlib by default)

`--compress-choice=zstd`: Enable zstd compression (faster and better compression than zlib)

`--compress-level=9`: Increase the compression level from the default of 3 (tradeoff vs maximum of 19)

`--checksum-choice=xxh3`: Use xxh3 hashing algorithm (very fast)

Comment: Neither `--compress` nor `--partial` is relevant for local filesystem copies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forcibly calling the `rsync` and hence all data is getting downloaded when you recall it again. use `--progress` option to copy only those files which are not copied and `--delete` option to delete any files if already copied and now it does not exist in source folder...

```
rsync -avz --progress --delete -e  /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2
```

If you are using ssh to login to other system and copy the files,

```
rsync -avz --progress --delete -e "ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o \
StrictHostKeyChecking=no" /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2
```

let me know if there is any mistake in my understanding of this concept...

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and explain what your special ssh call does, and why you advice to do it?

Comment: @Fabien He tells rsync to set two ssh options (rsync uses ssh to connect). The second one tells ssh to not prompt for confirmation if the host he's connecting to isn't already known (by existing in the "known hosts" file). The first one tells ssh to not use the default known hosts file (which would be ~/.ssh/known_hosts). He uses /dev/null instead, which is of course always empty, and as ssh would then not find the host in there, it would normally prompt for confirmation, hence option two. Upon connecting, ssh writes the now known host to /dev/null, effectively forgetting it instantly :)

Comment: ...but you were probably wondering what effect, if any, it has on the rsync operation itself. The answer is none. It only serves to not have the host you're connecting to added to your SSH known hosts file. Perhaps he's a sysadmin often connecting to a great number of new servers, temporary systems or whatnot. I don't know :)

Comment: "use --progress option to copy only those files which are not copied" What?

Comment: There are a couple errors here; one is very serious: `--delete` will delete files **in the destination** that don't exist in the source. The less serious one is that `--progress` doesn't modify how things are copied; it just gives you a progress report on each file as it copies. (I fixed the serious error; replaced it with `--remove-source-files`.)

Answer (score 0):

For those using the GUI Grsync, the matching configuration is the following:

In the "Advanced options" tab, check (at least) the checkbox "**Keep partially transferred files**".

Then in the "Additionnal options" field, enter:

```
--append-verify
```

Then **File** -> **Simulation** : to check whether the transfer will work (if you encounter error you might want to check the other options selected, source & destination).
And finally **File** -> **Execute**.

With this configuration if the transfer fails, you can just close the transfer window and **File** -> **Execute** again. It will resume the transfer where it was interrupted.

Comment: You really do not want to force checksums. It's desperately inefficient

Comment: @roaima It actually increases processing time, and is not necessary, you are right. I will edit my answer accordingly. Best.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying between two local filesystems. This disables almost all the optimisations offered by `rsync` and implicitly enables `--wholefile`. Furthermore you have involved NTFS filesystems that don't necessarily keep enough of the metadata that `rsync` uses to check a file has been correctly copied.

Try this,

```
sudo rsync -rtv /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2
```