# Interrupting rsync with ctrl-c, should I use `--partial` or `--append`?

Tags: rsync, file-transfer

I would like to interrupt `rsync` with `ctrl-c` (let's say after half the file has transferred) and resume without having to resend the data that has already been transferred.

The stackexchange/google information I have found seems conflicting. I found some some who say use `--partial` and some who say use `--append`. To me it sounds like they both would work.

**If I want to interrupt rsync with ctrl-c, should I use `--partial` or `--append`?**

**If both would work, when is it better to use one vs the other?**

Answer (score 9):

To restart, `--partial` is sufficient. Use `--inplace` if you really don't want `rsync` to create a temporary file that merges the existing copied data and the new, for example if `rsync` will have permissions issues creating a temporary file in the target folder.

Only use `--append` if you can guarantee that the partially copied data is still identical to the source. (Generally this is a false optimisation.)

Comment: so when i use the above options (actually using --append-verify) and rsync *still* claims it is starting from the beginning, and I don't see any change in the file-size and the remaining file time is what it originally was when I started the copy, is rsync lying, or should I be worried?

Comment: @Michael if you have a local source and destination all the rules change.

Comment: I was doing it across the LAN, but after a bit more experimenting, it appears that the issue is that since `--append-verify` actually has to actually read the parts of the file on both sides that are there, t isn't any faster due to the bottleneck being an older drive on the read side and not the LAN itself.

Comment: @Michael well yes, if you've asked for verification of the data already transmitted then it has to read the data!

Comment: The rule I've been using is --append only for single files, such as a pre-gzipped directory or sqldump

Comment: @DmitriDB you can use `--append` anywhere, but only if you can guarantee all affected files haven't changed. (I also tend to use it only for a very tightly controlled set of files; most of the time I treat it as an unsafe optimisation.)

Comment: How about `--partial-dir` ? @roaima

Comment: Here(https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252969/198423) `--partial-dir` also recommended. Is it recommended to use instead of `--partial` ?

Comment: @alper I've never noticed that option before. It looks like it would be best to use `--partial-dir`, but I've not yet tried it.

Answer (score 4):

- `--append` presumes the file may already exist in the destination, it just makes rsync not check the content already there (but see below).
- `--partial` tells rsync to not delete partially transferred files.

You'll also need `--inplace` with `--partial` (it is implied with `--append`).

Turns out `--inplace` actually implies `--partial`, this is why `--append` is enough (it implies `--inplace` which implies `--partial`). But `--partial` alone is not enough, you need `--inplace`, otherwise rsync creates temp files instead of updating the final one.

Comment: If I want to interrupt rsync with ctrl-c, I would use `--append`? Because `--partial` by itself would not resume.

Comment: I'd use just `--inplace`. rsync "always resumes" (it tries to transfer the minimal data needed). What `--append` does is tell rsync to not checksum the data already at the destination, so if the partial file at the destination has been corrupted, it will stay corrupted with `--append`. `--append` might be interesting if, say, the partial file is very large and you can't wait (and is sure or don't care if it's corrupted), or some other specific situation.

Comment: on Fedora 20 `man rsync` the option `--append` says `... Implies --inplace`

Comment: `--inplace` will work. `--append` will work because (as I stated in the answer) it implies `--inplace`, which implies `--partial` (which will keep partially transferred files when interrupted by Ctrl-c, which was the original question). So `--append` means "do as `--inplace`, but **don't checksum what's already in the destination**. It is an important difference. If you don't care about it, use either.

Comment: so then what's the point of `--partial` **WITHOUT** `--inplace`

Comment: Check out the `--partial-dir` option. By default rsync only changes the destination file after the transfer is complete (i.e. it avoids leaving broken files in use). If the transfer is interrupted it deletes the temporary file without updating the destination. With `--partial` it will leave the temporary file there when interrupted. Though IIRC, my memory may be wrong, `--partial` only resumes properly when also using `--partial-dir`, otherwise I had eventual surprises with leftover partial temporary files lying around.

Comment: Or, in another way to see it: use `--partial` with `--partial-dir` if there's risk the transfer is interrupted and the destination can't have broken/partial files in use.