Rsync does not continue transfer after laptop wakes from sleep
Rsync local source and fuse mounted cloud destination transfer hangs and laptop wifi stops working because closing lid suspends laptop. Wifi restored but rsync does not continue with file transfer.
I didn't run rsync with -P:
rsync -vva --exclude source dest 1>out.log 2>err.log

$ ps aux | grep rsync
user   738104  0.0  0.0 229708  2560 pts/6    S+   00:06   0:27 rsync -vva --exclude cloudDrive/ /home /home/user/cloudDrive/backup/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00
user   738105  0.0  0.0 289016  1876 pts/6    S+   00:06   0:00 rsync -vva --exclude cloudDrive/ /home /home/user/cloudDrive/backup/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00
user   738119  0.0  0.0 307384  1476 pts/6    D+   00:06   0:32 rsync -vva --exclude cloudDrive/ /home /home/user/cloudDrive/backup/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00
user   749293  0.0  0.0 221632  1536 pts/4    S+   00:16   0:00 tail -f /tmp/rsync_backup_out.log
user   983692  0.0  0.0 221632  1408 pts/7    S+   01:00   0:00 tail -f /tmp/rsync_backup_err.log
user  1199890  0.0  0.0 224692  2304 pts/8    S+   10:27   0:00 man rsync
user  1199899  0.0  0.0 224528   888 pts/8    S+   10:27   0:00 man rsync
user  1263878  0.0  0.0 222436  2176 pts/18   S+   16:41   0:00 grep --color=auto rsync

rsync  version 3.3.0  protocol version 31

Update:
I accidentally cancelled the rsync process with Ctrl+C so the question now is, will using --partial on the next run of rsync skip already transferred files and only transfer the remaining in the source directory?

Rsync always tries to skip already transferred files.  You don't need to add any options to accomplish that.
Normally during an interruption rsync will just discard any file that was inflight.   --partial will ask it to leave the transferred part.   Unless you have huge files that you're having problems transferring in a session, you probably don't want to add that flag.

--partial
By default, rsync will delete any partially transferred file if the transfer is interrupted. In some circumstances it is more
desirable to keep partially transferred files. Using the --partial
option tells rsync to keep the partial file which should make a
subsequent transfer of the rest of the file much faster.


First paragraph not strictly true. You need -t (--times) to make it work properly

This answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165417/289865 explains that with or without --partial, rsync keeps partially transfered files. With --partial rsync keeps it in-place while without --partial keeps it in a temporary file named similarly to the original file. --append is needed on the next run of rsync in order to resume incompleted file transfers by updating destination files that were partially transferred.
Initially it was not clear to me whether --append only updates existing files or if it also copies source files that don't exist in the destination, and I considered that maybe the latter is rsync's default behaviour? Now I realise the following answers this question:
Based on this from the manpage

Rsync finds files that need to be transferred using a "quick check" algorithm (by default) that looks for files that have changed in size or in last-modified time.

rsync will always transfer new files because for files that don't
exist in the destination (i.e. new files) source file modified time >
None or source file size > None. Adding --append just means that for
source file modified time > destination file modified time or source
file size > destination file size, rsync will update instead of
copying the whole source file.
