# How to run a program multiple times with different arguments using a loop in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm looking to run multiple instances of a python script with each instance being fed an incremental argument. So the bash script would do something like that :

```
for i from 1 to 10 do
    python script.py i
```

All scripts should run at the same time from one console of course. Any idea how to do that  ?

Comment: add & to run in background http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103731/run-a-command-without-making-me-wait

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To simply run the program ten times,
with the (incremented) iteration number as an argument, do this:

```
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++))
do
    python script.py "$i"
done
```

[As Kamaraj says](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/329998/80216#comment580599_329998), to get the ten processes to run at the same time
(i.e., simultaneously / concurrently), add `&` to the command:

```
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++))
do
    python script.py "$i" &
done
```